# New createJS toolkit for flash

Tags: createjs

Adobe changed the way createJS toolkit is now working. in a result, my files no longer works.
I used the */ (remark syntax) for coding, so what do I do with my previous file - do I still need to use this syntax? the new publish option remove those remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Using CreateJS toolkit from Flash CS6. You can export your file along with code written inside the action panel but you must wrap your code using

```
/* js 
(code goes here)
/*
```

Note that JavaScript doesn't support typed variables, you need to use "this" when referencing the current scope.

ex:

```
this.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

/* js

its very sensative

/*js does not work

/* js     onespace  works

/*  js   two space  works

/*   js  three space  does not work

http://graphicscoder.org/my-createjs/comment-in-flash-for-createjs/